# thenReturn a data class in using mockito with kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I want to create a unit testing by using mockito in my viewmodel code but i dont know how to use mockito `thenReturn` for a single data class contained some information . can somebody help me, please.

here is my viewModel class code which I created :

```
open class DetailViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var dataCollection:SendDetail  = SendDetail("",0,"","","","")

    fun getData(data:SendDetail){
        dataCollection.title=data.title
        dataCollection.picture=data.picture
        dataCollection.category= "Category : " + data.category
        dataCollection.genre= "Genre : \n" + data.genre
        dataCollection.release= "Release : \n" + data.release
        dataCollection.description= "Description : \n" + data.description
    }
}
```

and here are my unit testing code for code above :

```
class DetailViewModelTest {

    private lateinit var viewModel: DetailViewModel
    private var sendDetail= SendDetail("",0,"","","","")
    private val sampleDetail:MovieData = MovieDataObject.listData[1]

    private var dummyDetail= SendDetail("Doctor Who",
        2131165337,
        "Category : " +"Tv Series",
        "Genre : \n" +"Action, Adventure, Drama, Fantasy, Sci-fi",
        "Release : \n" +"March 26, 2005",
        "Description : \n"+ "The Doctor is a Time Lord: a 900 year old alien with 2 hearts, part of a gifted civilization who mastered time travel. The Doctor saves planets for a living – more of a hobby actually, and the Doctor's very, very good at it.")

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        viewModel = DetailViewModel()
        sendDetail.title=sampleDetail.title
        sendDetail.picture=sampleDetail.picture
        sendDetail.category="Category : " +sampleDetail.category
        sendDetail.genre="Genre : \n" +sampleDetail.genre
        sendDetail.release="Release : \n" +sampleDetail.release
        sendDetail.description="Description : \n"+sampleDetail.description
    }

    @Test
    fun getData() {
        val movieEntities = viewModel.getData(sendDetail)
        assertNotNull(movieEntities)
        assertEquals(dummyDetail,sendDetail)
    }

    @Test
    fun testMockGetData() {
        Mockito.`when`(viewModel.getData(sendDetail)).thenReturn(dummyDetail)   // <--- this dummyDetail is the problem
        val movieEntities = viewModel.getData(sendDetail)
        verify(viewModel).getData(sendDetail)
        assertEquals(dummyDetail, movieEntities)
    }

}
```

and this is the error message :

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is SendDetail but Unit! was expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `fun getData(data:SendDetail)` has a return type of void.

Just add the return type after the parameters, for example: `fun getData(data:SendDetail): String`